# Azure Data Factory blob dataset using gzip compression started throwing validation error

Tags: azure, gzip, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have parquet blob datasets defined in my Data Factory using gzip compression. The files have a '.parquet' extension. Copy activities and data flows have been working fine with these parquet blobs for the last 6 months.

Today I started getting following validation error when editing my pipeline:

```
Gzip compression in data flow only supports files with ".gz"
extension. Please update the file name configuration or choose another
compression type.
```

Has something changed in the ADF service?

Where can I read more about this breaking change and when it was introduced?

Comment: I did not find any related announcements. And, there is no such error thrown here. This is the parquet file I post: https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/test3/output.parquet and it is no problem. Can you have a try?

Comment: Are you using gzip compression? If yes can you go back and try validating your dataset in ADF?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFbCU.png

Comment: You can find no validation error and I can success get the value.

Comment: I am sorry the file url is broken, now it is ok: https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/test3/output.parquet I am not sure maybe something wrong with your parquet file? You can have a try.

Comment: Ok I tried with a new parquet file and was able to reproduce the issue. Please try to use your dataset in a data flow, and validate the data flow. The source of the validation error is the data flow and not the dataset itself..

Comment: Okey, please wait, I need to start data flow debug module.

Comment: Yes, I face the same problem. Just change the suffix to .gz seems solved this problem.

Comment: I want to understand the impact of this service change, when it was introduced, and where its documented before I make code changes to our 100+ datasets.

Comment: Did not find any official announcement, the offcial doc still say .parquet in dataflow is allowed. I will help you consult the official, maybe the product group has some updates. Any update will let you know.

Comment: It is annoying that ADF service keeps introducing breaking changes without any announcement or notification in advance. This has not happened to me for the first time.

Comment: Did you use gzip compression type to read .parquet file in the last 6 months in azure data flow and face no problem?

Comment: @coder_andy you have a compressed  file which contains many '.parquet' files. What's the extension of the compressed file, zip?

Comment: Hi, have you check it? Now it should been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is been solved. Please have a check, This is not a major update, it is a bug and it has now been fixed:

[image]

[image]

You can check the update here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, we entered a support ticket and the fix was deployed within a week.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this same problem on 8/3/20, and opened a support ticket with Microsoft on 8/4/20. The response was that it is a known problem, is on track to be fixed this week.